# Handle Unique field in Flask WTF

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am using Flask WTF for my application and created a form.
I have defined unique in model.

**Flask WTF**:
`packet_id = StringField("Packet ID", validators=[DataRequired()])`

**Flask SQL-Alchemy Model** : `packet_id = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)`

and handling it like this

```
def validate_packet_id(self, packet_id):
        if packet_id.data is None:
            raise ValidationError("Name field is required.")
        else:
            packet = TableName.query.filter_by(packet_id=packet_id.data).first()

            if packet:
                raise ValidationError('That packet ID already exists. Please choose a different one.')
```

This code works perfectly with the post method, but when I use update It shows an error that packet_id already exists. 
Can anyone help me how to check the packet_id in DB except this current row id?

Comment: Have you looked at the `.update()` method? Is that what you're attempting?

Comment: @bernie I am saving the data with this form, when I validate the form on update it fails.